# Error During Rails Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find out if this error during my rails installation matters at all

```
Installing RDoc documentation for builder-3.0.4...
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding : ignored
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding  ignored
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding : ignored
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding  ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly not since this just occurred in the generation of the documentation for Builder (as opposed to something that could affect your code at runtime). But [here](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/issues/39) is an explanation of the issue for your version.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will only affect usage of the help documentation (that is what RDoc is for) so wouldn't actually affect rails itself.

I've seen a few doc issues lately.  For some of them `gem install rdoc` to upgrade to the latest version of the RDoc package itself has helped.